# Stability using Phonon Calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, crystallography, phonons, phonon-dispersion

While performing phonon calculation using finite difference method, we get normal modes printed in the outcar file. Now there is a distinction between two different types of modes in the outcar file.

The first type of mode is the one where a number if followed by 'f' which indicated vibrationally stable mode. The other mode is represented by a number followed by 'f/i' which is called as 'soft mode' and this mode is imaginary.[Link](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Phonons_from_finite_differences)

Now the soft mode represents a certain kind of movement of atoms where the crystal translates from higher symmetry to lower symmetry with respect to the change in temperature. However I fail to understand if this actually states that the structure becomes unstable.[Link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_soft_phonon_in_ferroelectrics)

Answer (score 7):

The basic quantity you build when performing a phonon calculation is the matrix of force constants, given by:

$$
D_{i\alpha,i^{\prime}\alpha^{\prime}}(\mathbf{R}_p,\mathbf{R}_{p^{\prime}})=\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial u_{p\alpha i}\partial u_{p^{\prime}\alpha^{\prime}i^{\prime}}},
$$

where $E$ is the potential energy surface in which the nuclei move, $u_{p\alpha i}$ is the displacement of atom $\alpha$ (of all atoms in the basis), in Cartesian direction $i$ ($x$, $y$, $z$), and located in the cell within the supercell at $\mathbf{R}_p$. Mathematically speaking, this matrix of force constants is the Hessian matrix of the potential energy function $E$. As for any Hessian matrix, its eigenvalues give the curvature of the function $E$ along the direction of the associated eigenvectors, and we can have:

- Positive eigenvalue: the curvature is positive, which means that the function $E$ is a minimum along that direction.
- Negative eigenvalue: the curvature is negative, which means that the function $E$ is a maximum along that direction.

To relate this to your question, note that the phonon frequencies are the *square root* of the eigenvalues above, so positive eigenvalues give positive phonon frequencies and negative eigenvalues give imaginary phonon frequencies (your soft modes).

This means that imaginary frequencies are associated with maxima of $E$, so that displacing that atoms along the corresponding eigenvectors will lower the energy (make $E$ smaller). As a dynamically stable structure is one defined at a (local) minimum of $E$, then whenever you have imaginary frequencies you are not at a local minimum (you are at a saddle point), so the structure is unstable. By distorting the structure along the eigenvector associated with the imaginary mode, you will be able to find a lower energy structure.

The addition of temperature can stabilize an otherwise unstable structure, but for that one needs to include anharmonic terms in the calculation (i.e. phonon-phonon interactions), so the harmonic calculations you are performing cannot resolve this question of stability at finite temperature.